# Three.js won't load blender model

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, collada

I am new to Blender (using 2.70a) and I made a mesh from a bezier curve. [File: http://ivybaumgarten.com/3d/models/wiggler5.blend ]

Exporting it to three.js format gives just a shell of an export with nothing inside: http://pastebin.com/aVNnjE5f

Exporting it as Collada contains something that looks promising (http://pastebin.com/XFf7wMR8 ), but if I replace monster.dae from this example (http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html) with my model, it doesn't show up. Exporting just a cube shows up fine.

In Blender, it also appears in Texture view, but when I switch over to Rendered, it's blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A friend pointed out that the export was empty because I hadn't selected anything before exporting. Selecting the model before exporting made the model show up in my three.js project.

I still don't know why Render is empty.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know three.js and collada but if you want to export your mesh or a scene in order to show it through the Web via WebGL, I suggest you to use [babylonjs](http://www.babylonjs.com/). I have already done an export from 2.69 & 2.71 and it works well.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The best answers explain how to do things, often with code examples. In addition, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.